# MEDIAN IF statement not populating a number

Tags: microsoft-excel

Below in my screenshot, you can see the data I am working with. I am trying to get the median for any "Filtered Rate" that has a "Success", Launch Status.

Here is the formula that I am using. The result keeps populating a 0.00 result.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

`=MEDIAN(IF(D3:D19=P11,E3:E19))`

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @ScottCraner Excel 2016

Comment: Are you using Ctrl-Shift-Enter to verify the array formula instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: @ScottCraner I was not. I didn't even know that was a thing. It did the trick for me though, Thanks!

Comment: With versions previous to the advent of Dynamic Array formula in Office 365, one needs to confirm all array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Thanks for the help!